# How to read a Fernet key from terminal input

Tags: python, encryption, input, terminal

This is probably not the best way to go about it but I've been learning Python and decided to set up a tiny local server that uses Fernet cryptography to save API_keys.

Currently I save an encrypted randomly generated API_KEY into a database.

I do it like this:

```
char_num = 24
allchar = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
random_api = "".join(random.choice(allchar) for x in range(char_num))
print("generated api ")
print(random_api)
crypt_key = Fernet.generate_key()
fernet_key = Fernet(crypt_key)
print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print(crypt_key)
print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
encrypted_api = fernet_key.encrypt(bytes(random_api,encoding="ascii"))
users_cursor.execute('insert into entries values(?,?)',(0,encrypted_api,))
#c.execute('insert into entries values(?,?)',(1,encrypted_api,))

print("Encrypted API")
users_conn.commit()
users_conn.close()
```

The crypt_key then needs to be saved by whoever is "administrating" the server. Then at boot-up this value is then saved as a variable value using input()

```
    print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
crypt_key = input("Input your Crypt key: ")
print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
fernet_key = Fernet(crypt_key)
```

This is probably generating a problem as I am inputting the fernet generated key into the terminal.

The key is later used to decrypt the values in the database and compared to the api key that was inputted in the GET REQUEST.

```
user_conn = sqlite3.connect("users.db")
decrypted_api_key = fernet_key.decrypt(api_key)
legitimity = user_conn.execute("SELECT * FROM ENTRIES WHERE key=?",(key,))
legitimity = legitimity.fetchone()
if legitimity is None:
    return "Wrong API"
```

Sample run:

Generated key: **b'Xxny-xTZ_IJuJMPrgM2BfgZMB4-tR5htqXOwTvNwlcU='**

GET REQUEST: **"GET /submit/number=31&key=nSofO4UeYZzDuoiEby08relZ?**

The key I inputted into the terminal: **Xxny-xTZ_IJuJMPrgM2BfgZMB4-tR5htqXOwTvNwlcU=**

```
Stack trace:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/davidv7/Documents/pyDev/primeNumbersServer/main.py", line 131, in submit
    admin_bool = check_for_admin(api_key)
  File "/home/davidv7/Documents/pyDev/primeNumbersServer/main.py", line 93, in check_for_admin
    decrypted_api_key = fernet_key.decrypt(bytes(key,encoding="ascii"))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 74, in decrypt
    timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 88, in _get_unverified_token_data
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

I've read up on the issues and the issue is:

```
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken – If the token is in any way invalid, this exception is raised. A token may be invalid for a number of reasons: it is older than the ttl, it is malformed, or it does not have a valid signature.
```

This makes me believe the issues is not even me inputting my key into the terminal in a wrong way because that would probably be calling this exception:

TypeError – This exception is raised if token is not bytes

I will also provide a screenshot of my terminal input :

[image: Terminal]

Steps I've taken:

1. Checked for rogue spaces

This list might get expanded in the future when I think of stuff.